# Prolog Set Difference Relation

Tags: prolog, set

Define the set subtraction relation in Prolog:

```
difference( Set 1, Set 2, SetDifference)
```

where all the three sets are represented as lists. For example:

```
difference( [a,b,c,d], [b,d,e,f], [a,c])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Homework? Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

Such a function is generally included in Prolog systems.  This makes me think it's an arbitrary homework assignment, and I wonder what the rules are.  Presumably you can't call set_difference.  Can you use member/2?  Are the lists sorted or not?  Should the function work in all modes (+++, ++-, -++, +-+), and backtrack to produce alternative answers?

If doing such a function from scratch, the best approach is to think in English, and think inductively.
How do you answer the simplest case:  The difference between two empty lists is an empty list.  difference([],[],[]).
What if you add to one of the lists?  To the other?  Each answer gets a clause.

Beyond that, the answer depends on the rules of the assignment.